# HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available - springMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm building spring mvc application with spring security.
This is my url :

http://localhost:8080/inbalUI/login

And I'm getting to my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String loginPage() {
             if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
                    return "login";
             } else {
                    return "login";
                    // return "redirect:/list";
             }
       }
```

This is the log :

20:02:10.823 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
20:02:10.825 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
20:02:10.825 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
20:02:10.825 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
20:02:10.825 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

This is the login.jsp deploying path on tomcat :

C:\me\apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\inbalUI\WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF\views

But I'm getting HTTP Status 404:

HTTP Status 404 - /inbalUI/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
type Status report
message /inbalUI/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/8.0.36

Any idea why ?

Comment: Because the jsp should be at /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp, not at WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp.

Comment: yes I fixed my deployment assembly and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you use the wrong folder for views.

According to this article https://vitalflux.com/web-application-folder-structure-spring-mvc-web-projects/ this folder should be at:

```
src/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
```

and you probably put it under

```
src/resources/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
```

Which results in `WEB-INF/views/login.jsp` being put into the classpath (`classes/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp`)